# How to read child in json and python?

Tags: python, json

I would like to read a json file in python and extract the information.Here is a part of my json file:

```
{"diagnostics": 
   {"updated_at":"2019-03-24T15:32:28.272Z"
   ,"payload":
      {"service":    
         {"publish":
         ...
```

Here is my python code:

```
import json
import requests

url="https://XXXXX/diagnostics/XXXXX/last?access_token=XXXXX"
data=requests.get(url)
jData=data.json()

for x in jData['diagnostics']:
    print x['updated_at']
```

When I run my code, I am supposed to get 2019-03-24T15:32:28.272Z as the result but I get an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "fileName.py", line 10 in <module>
 print x['updated_at']
TypeError: string indices must be integer
```

I guess, my code sees 'diagnostics' as an object ONLY! The child in that object (which are updated_at and payload) are being seeing as string. Why?

Comment: {"diagnostics":{"updated_at":"2019-03-24T15:32:28.272Z","payload":{"service":{"cloud":{"publish"

Comment: No, that's looks like yaml but this is not a valid one.

Comment: I insert the raw json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the inner dictionary by getting the value of `diagnostics` key first, which will get you the nested dictionary. Then get the value of the `updated_at` key from that:

```
jData['diagnostics']['updated_at']
```

---

In your code, by doing:

```
for x in jData['diagnostics']:
```

you are iterating over the nested dict keys, which are strings. So, when you subscript the fist key with a string i.e. `updated_at`, you're getting the `TypeError` saying the string objects are only integer index-able.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: @ReyBaf No problem. Glad I could help :)